# what do when we get a error in Splunk eval command

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard, splunk-formula, splunk-calculation

For this Splunk query:

```
index=* | eval case(status="200", "is successful", status="300", is redirect, status="400", "is error", 1=1", is did not match")
```

I expected that I would get a result with a list of 200 as successful & 300 is as redirect 400 as error, but my eval command as error

Answer (score 2):

There appear to be a couple of issues with your use of the [`case` statement](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/ConditionalFunctions).

1. You need to assign the result of the case statement to a
   field that can be used.
2. The quotes for your values are not correct. `is redirect` doesn't have any, and `is did not match"` has a trailing quote, but not a leading quote.
3. You should use `==` and not `=` when testing the `status`
   values.
4. You need to do something with the results of your `case`

Try something like this:

```
index=* 
| eval label = case(status=="200", "is successful", status=="300", "is redirect", status=="400", "is error", 1=1", "is did not match")
| stats count by label
```